# jquery resize with iframes and div tag

Tags: jquery, html, resize

I'm reading about jquery-resize http://jqueryui.com/resizable/
I have html page with 3 div tags and 1 iframe - like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/reset.css" />

<body class="site">
   <div id="mytag1">
    <iframe src="/some/path/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
   </div>

   <div id="mytag2">

     <div id="mytag3">
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like allow user to resize the iframe included inside div-id#mytag1
How to do that?thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `iframe` fit the `div` that contains it. So set its CSS style properties `width` and `height` to `100%`.

Then set the size of the `div` and make it `resizable()`.

Is this what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/PHbHN/?